# How many ways are there to choose $6$ children from $7$ boys and $4$ girls on condition that at least one is a girl?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 7 boys and 4 girls in the kindergarten.

How many ways are there to choose 6 of them on condition that at least one is a girl.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your attempts on the question.

Comment: $$\binom {11}6-\binom76$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use complementary counting. We wish to find the number of ways to select $6$ kids such that *none* is a girl, and then subtract this from the *total* number of groups. We will use combinations, not permutations.

The total number of groups with $6$ kids is $\dbinom{11}{6}.$

If no girls are in the group, everyone must be a boy. Since there are $7$ boys, we can choose $6$ of them in $\dbinom{7}{6} = 7$ ways.

The final answer is $\dbinom{11}{6} - 7 = \boxed{455}$ ways.